# Name and room owners for the main chat room

Tags: discussion, chat

This community has a chat room: [Materials Modeling](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107323/materials-modeling)

This is the third place, where people can meet up and discuss. It's the most casual of the three, with sometimes realtime back-and-forth. That's actually encouraged there.

It probably come with little to no surprise, that it is part of [the Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223674/260760). A few people have been chatting there already, but I invite everyone to come on over and check it out.

Right now the room profited from a few moderators (including me) being there and doing a little maintenance if necessary. Until this community is established enough to have its own appointed/elected moderator(s) (and maybe beyond) I propose to appoint room owners. They will be able to manage feeds and messages, description and a few other things.

Since Nike Datani has invested a lot in this site, and is very active here and there, I suppose he's an ideal candidate. I'd appoint him to that position, if all y'all agree... (You can upvote this post to signalise that.)
If you would like other people, too, please suggest them (in an answer, please).

Furthermore, we're looking for an awesome name for the room. On Physics it's called 'The h Bar', Chemistry has 'The Periodic Table', Code Review has 'The 2nd Monitor', Biology has 'The Biosphere', you get the gist... . Obviously, you can go like Mathematics with just 'Mathematics'. Your choice.

Your idea can be an answer just down below.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, Nike would be a good owner of the room.

I suggest the room name  "**Meta Matter**"

It has the exact meaning of what it reflects and the double meaning of referring to materials e.g.

> A metamaterial is defined as a synthetic material with properties not
>   usually found in natural materials.

- I edited it from Meta Matters to Meta Matter

Comment: I've appointed Nike as RO. The rest can be done when this site has moderators.